# How to create a parametric equation for a curve using data points

Tags: functions, parametric, data-analysis

After performing a loess regression I have a set of points that predict a curve and I would like to create a parametric function that would fit this curve with a good degree of accuracy, but i'm not sure how. How would I create the equation? The output data below is for an input of 0 to 9.9 intervals are set at 0.1

To be clear, I'm not looking to perform another regression, I want an equation that I can write in the form f(x)=....

1.003883 1.005017 1.006127 1.007213 1.008276 1.009313 1.010323 1.011307 1.012268 1.013208 1.014128 1.015031 1.015917 1.016774 1.017589 1.018366 1.019108 1.019821 1.020507 1.021173 1.021821 1.022456 1.023082 1.023704 1.024326 1.024951 1.025585 1.026216 1.026836 1.027445 1.028046 1.028640 1.029231 1.029819 1.030407 1.030996 1.031590 1.032189 1.032795 1.033411 1.034039 1.034677 1.035314 1.035950 1.036584 1.037219 1.037854 1.038489 1.039126 1.039764 1.040404 1.041046 1.041691 1.042340 1.042992 1.043649 1.044310 1.044975 1.045643 1.046313 1.046986 1.047660 1.048335 1.049011 1.049687 1.050363 1.051040 1.051715 1.052390 1.053063 1.053735 1.054404 1.055071 1.055736 1.056397 1.057054 1.057709 1.058364 1.059017 1.059670 1.060322 1.060972 1.061622 1.062272 1.062920 1.063568 1.064214 1.064860 1.065505 1.066150 1.066793 1.067436 1.068078 1.068719 1.069360 1.069999 1.070638 1.071277 1.071914 1.072551

[Plotted Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Icm.png)

Comment: You probably won't be able to come up with a simple expression that fits this data exactly, so you'll have to decide which desire to give up.  One thing you might do to start is plot the function, plot the first and second differences, and see if any  functional form springs to mind.  If any of these plots have kinks or seeming discontinuities you will have to think harder about what you really want.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem for a computer.  In *Mathematica*:

```
data = {1.003883, 1.005017, 1.006127, 1.007213, 1.008276, 1.009313, 
  1.010323, 1.011307, 1.012268, 1.013208, 1.014128, 1.015031, 
  1.015917, 1.016774, 1.017589, 1.018366, 1.019108, 1.019821, 
  1.020507, 1.021173, 1.021821, 1.022456, 1.023082, 1.023704, 
  1.024326, 1.024951, 1.025585, 1.026216, 1.026836, 1.027445, 
  1.028046, 1.028640, 1.029231, 1.029819, 1.030407, 1.030996, 
  1.031590, 1.032189, 1.032795, 1.033411, 1.034039, 1.034677, 
  1.035314, 1.035950, 1.036584, 1.037219, 1.037854, 1.038489, 
  1.039126, 1.039764, 1.040404, 1.041046, 1.041691, 1.042340, 
  1.042992, 1.043649, 1.044310, 1.044975, 1.045643, 1.046313, 
  1.046986, 1.047660, 1.048335, 1.049011, 1.049687, 1.050363, 
  1.051040, 1.051715, 1.052390, 1.053063, 1.053735, 1.054404, 
  1.055071, 1.055736, 1.056397, 1.057054, 1.057709, 1.058364, 
  1.059017, 1.059670, 1.060322, 1.060972, 1.061622, 1.062272, 
  1.062920, 1.063568, 1.064214, 1.064860, 1.065505, 1.066150, 
  1.066793, 1.067436, 1.068078, 1.068719, 1.069360, 1.069999, 
  1.070638, 1.071277, 1.071914, 1.072551};

fitfun = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3}, x]
```

$1.0453 + 0.0008714 x - 4.4225 \times 10^{-6} x^2 + 2.59026 \times 10^{-8} x^3$

```
Show[
 ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 Plot[fitfun, {x, 0, 100}]
 ]
```

[image]

Obviously if you want a better fit, use more terms:

If you use `fitfun = Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x]`

you get:

[image]

Comment: The function looks inconsistent with the graph. x=0 should give 1.0453, but it looks like your graph shows <1.01 at x=0.

Comment: Clearly the quality of the fit depends upon the order of series used.  I used up to $x^3$.  If you want a better fit, use more terms.  Basic and ancient curve-fitting methodology.

Comment: @GabrielMunson. Take care : in the data, the first "hidden" value of $x$ is $1$ and not $0$.

Comment: Take care : in the data, the first "hidden" value of $x$ is $1$ and not $0$ (as far as I remember how works Mathematica with   $data=\{y_1,y_2,\cdots,y_n\}$.

Answer (score 0):

As David G. Stork answered, fitting data with polynomials is a quite easy task (you can do it using Excel).

You also could use fitting techniques with rational approximations, the model being
$$y=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i}{1+\sum_{i=1}^m b_ix^i}$$ selecting the degrees $m,n$ of numerator and denominator.

Looking at your data, which look to be quite linear for the large values of $x$, it seems that $m=n-1$ could be a good idea.

So, using $n=3$ (as David G. Stork did in his first example) and $m=2$, the adjusted model is 
$$y=\frac{1.00314-0.0503071 x+0.00380452
   x^2+2.59032\times 10^{-6}x^3}{1-0.0510772 x+0.00382303 x^2}$$ for which all parameters are highly significant from a statistical point of view.

**Remark** : as tehy have been used, your data are supposed to start at $x=1$ and not at $x=0$ with an increment of $1$. So, for the first fit, the first $y$ is predicted to be $1.00540$ and $1.00409$ for the second model (to be compared to the experimental value $1.003883$.